# Making plots with data and error bars (non linear fit)

Tags: plotting, data

I have some data from let's say x,y which I would like to plot with error bars. I have the error from y only, it is 5% of each value of y. I have already made the plot, but I need to do a non linear regression so I need the error bars too. Can someone tell me how they would solve this?
This is my data:

```
w = {9.43396*10^(11), 1.11524*10^(12), 1.27119*10^(12), 1.5*10^(12), 1.81818*10^(12), 2.0979*10^(12), 2.4*10^(12), 2.7027*10^(12), 3.*10^(12), 3.30033*10^(12), 3.60144*10^(12), 3.90117*10^(12), 4.20168*10^(12), 4.49775*10^(12), 9.375*10^(12), 1.*10^(13), 1.07143*10^(13), 1.15385*10^(13), 1.25*10^(13), 1.36364*10^(13), 1.5*10^(13), 1.66667*10^(13), 1.875*10^(13), 2.14286*10^(13), 2.5*10^(13), 3.*10^(13), 3.75*10^(13), 4.28571*10^(13), 5.*10^(13), 6.*10^(13), 7.5*10^(13), 1.*10^(14), 2.41935*10^(13), 3.62757*10^(13), 4.83871*10^(13), 6.04839*10^(13), 7.26392*10^(13), 8.47458*10^(13), 9.67742*10^(13), 1.08696*10^(14), 1.20968*10^(14), 1.33333*10^(14), 1.44928*10^(14), 1.57068*10^(14), 1.69492*10^(14), 1.81818*10^(14), 1.93548*10^(14), 2.05479*10^(14), 2.17391*10^(14), 2.29008*10^(14), 2.41935*10^(14), 3.61446*10^(14), 4.83871*10^(14)};
e1 = {86163., 87360., 94656., 91800., 98651., 96012., 99663., 100277., 106095., 103455., 104075., 97200., 96632., 93841., 36860.2, 33660.4, 30573.8, 27251.8, 24086.8, 20788.4, 17700.8, 14833.1, 12194.3, 9511.71, 7142.4, 5054.19, 3293.46, 2535.89, 1875.78, 1306.64, 839.438, 474.75, 6789.09, 3077.6, 1734.35, 1113.63, 771.86, 565.878, 432.292, 342.029, 275.408, 227.901, 190.362, 161.232, 139.192, 118.774, 104.008, 91.5593, 81.1576, 72.0605, 64.464, 24.794, 9.9687};
e2 = {623116., 537272., 481490., 399798., 336540., 282384., 247384., 215364., 193112., 168392., 148932., 129600., 114426., 78960., 25371.2, 21734.4, 18382., 15253.2, 12448., 9886.4, 7670.4, 5778.4, 4188.8, 2859.4, 1840.32, 1089.66, 567.936, 382.79, 242.172, 141.18, 72.5, 30.52, 1352.95, 412.552, 177.642, 92.852, 55.044, 35.7, 24.544, 17.39, 12.948, 9.966, 7.728, 6.096, 5.192, 4.142, 3.672, 3.0624, 2.703, 2.3772, 2.0878, 0.7968, 0.8216};
erroe1 = {4308.15, 4368., 4732.8, 4590., 4932.55, 4800.6, 4983.15, 5013.85, 5304.75, 5172.75, 5203.75, 4860., 4831.6, 4692.05, 1843.01, 1683.02, 1528.69, 1362.59, 1204.34, 1039.42, 885.038, 741.656, 609.716, 475.586, 357.12, 252.709, 164.673, 126.794, 93.7888, 65.3319, 41.9719, 23.7375, 339.455, 153.88, 86.7177, 55.6814, 38.593, 28.2939, 21.6146, 17.1015, 13.7704, 11.3951, 9.51808, 8.06162, 6.95958, 5.9387, 5.20038, 4.57797, 4.05788, 3.60303, 3.2232, 1.2397, 0.498435};
erroe2 = {31155.8, 26863.6, 24074.5, 19989.9, 16827., 14119.2, 12369.2, 10768.2, 9655.6, 8419.6, 7446.6, 6480., 5721.3, 3948., 1268.56, 1086.72, 919.1, 762.66, 622.4, 494.32, 383.52, 288.92, 209.44, 142.97, 92.016, 54.483, 28.3968, 19.1395, 12.1086, 7.059, 3.625, 1.526, 67.6476, 20.6276, 8.8821, 4.6426, 2.7522, 1.785, 1.2272, 0.8695, 0.6474, 0.4983, 0.3864, 0.3048, 0.2596, 0.2071, 0.1836, 0.15312, 0.13515, 0.11886, 0.10439, 0.03984, 0.04108};
```

And this is the plot I made and where I want the error bars
[image]

THANK YOU!

Comment: Because you are fitting a nonlinear model, do you not want "error bands" for the estimated regression as opposed to or in addition to "error bars" for the data points?  Also, what is the nonlinear model that you are fitting?

Comment: You measured only a single point for a given x-value. Therefore it is not clear how you want to get errors in x direction.